# How to Connect More than One View Controller to Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have the following storyboards: [image: Storyboards]

"Home" is the default view controller. When you press the button in the top left with three lines, the menu view controller slides out (it's like a side menu). Within the menu there are four table cells that represent menu items, as you can see. When a cell is pressed, I have a corresponding function that is called. I want the view controller on the far right to be presented when a cell is pressed.

**Here's the issue:** I want the far right view controller to inherit the properties of the Home view controller, such that the navigation title and button are still there. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

Make sure that the navigation and right view controller are segued (Ctrl + Drag in Interface Builder)

Call the code stated in @bebzerk answer:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let transition = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as! RightViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(transition, animated: true)
```

Now go back to Interface builder, and add a UINavigationItem and a UIBarButtonItem to the view controller. Set the image of the button to the three lines and set the title of the navigation item to the name you want displayed on the top.

In the ViewController Swift file for the right view controller, Ctrl + Drag the bar button item and create an IBAction function. This will be called when the menu button (on the far right view controller is pressed). For me, this class extends from HomeViewController, so in the function, just called the super method. It should look like this:

```
@IBAction override func menuTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        super.menuTapped(UIBarButtonItem())
    }
```

This should achieve the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way ?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let transition = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as! RightViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(transition, animated: true)
```

It should open your *far right view controller* and makes it inherit your home controller, like with a back button

Test it and tell me if it's good to you.

Comment: No this doesn’t work. What happens when I have this is when I press the cell, it brings me to a view where instead of the three lined button, there’s a back button that takes me back to the home view controller